# Simple transpose in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to do a simple transpose in SQL Server and display 1 row and multiple columns. I have looked at pivot and unpivot and they seem too complex for this scenario. I am running a simple SQL query to get the rows:

```
select name 
from sys.databases 
where name like '%trn%'
```

Sample data:

```
prpc_trn
prpc_trn_arc
prpc_trn_IntegrationAuditDetails
prpc_trn_IntegrationAuditDetailsArchive
prpc_trn_Lumley
prpc_trn_PerformanceLoggingDetails
prpc_trn_PerformanceLoggingDetailsArchive
prpc_trn_prHistory
prpc_trn_prHistoryArchive
prpccpmi_trn
prpcref_trn
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, this can only be achieved by PIVOT. But just using PIVOT is probably not the best since the columns are dynamic.

Based on the following [article](http://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/), I think using XML with PIVOT is better option than just using PIVOT.

I attempted to write a query based on this article for your requirement:

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max), @query as nvarchar(max);

set @cols = stuff((select distinct ',' + quotename(c.[name])
            from   sys.databases c
            where name like '%trx%'
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
            , 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'select *  from (
  select name from sys.databases ) x pivot (max(name) for name in (' + @cols + ')) p '

execute (@query)
```

This can be improved by using better values for column names. The above query will use the table name itself as the column name.